# Is it possible to do an alternate Guard Impact?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

In soul caliburs 2-4 you could do a guard impact with either forward or back and G. The latter would cause your opponent to fall to the ground behind you. Is there still a way to do this in SC5?

Comment: Do you mean **parrying** (backwards directional + G)?

Comment: Yes, a parry. Back and G in SC5 does the forward parry, causing the opponent is repelled forward. There was an alternate way to do it in SC4 that causes them to fall.

Comment: I wonder why I got a -1 for asking this. Was there something unclear about the question? Was it poorly stated?

Answer (score 1):

Guard Impact is done with just 4A+B+K in Soul Calibur V. 4G and 1G "back parries" were removed. Guard Impact also covers all hit levels now, rather than having high/mid and mid/low versions.

Guard Impact also offers more frame advantage than in previous Soul Caliburs and gives guaranteed damage if the opponent does not re-GI. Despite GIs in SCV being arguably the best they've ever been, some players miss the complexity of the older systems.